# disabling dot-notation in eslint

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm having trouble disabling [dot-notation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/dot-notation) in eslint. Below is my eslint config (for the toy example):

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            4
        ],
        "dot-notation": 0,
        "no-console": 0,
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "double"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ]
    }
};
```

And here is my javascript:

```
var x = { a: 3 };
console.log("x[a] = " + x["a"]);
```

According to [this](https://github.com/jamesallardice/jslint-error-explanations/blob/master/message-articles/dot-notation.md), `0` is the way to turn off this eslint option. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Setting a rule value to `0` turns the rule off completely. This means that ESLint will not complain if you try to use an indexer rather than dot notation. It sounds like you're expecting the rule to either throw a warning or error which means that you need either a value of `1` (or `warn`) or `2` (or `error`) depending on how you want ESLint to behave.

The "Configuring Rules" section of "Configuring ESLint" should make it a little more clear:

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules

Comment: I do want to turn off the rule completely. However, eslint still throws an error in the case above.

Comment: Actually it turns out the problem was something else: in vim I had both jshint and eslint enabled. I thought the error was coming from eslint but it actually came from jshint.